# asp input field on click clear value

Tags: asp.net

I'm wanting to change the value of my inputs with my asp form fields so that when clicked it clears the content and if someone doesn't type any value and clicks another field it will re-add the default value again, if changed it leaves the new text.

eg. field:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="NameInfo"  CssClass="NameInfo" Width="300" runat="server" text="Name" />
```

Thanks in advance for any responses. I'm a beginner at asp so I'm not sure how to do these types of features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the functionality you need would be best achieved using jQuery and a plugin. Perhaps look into http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark which from experience works well.

You should just need to download that library and then have something like the following within the head tags of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/watermarkplugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#<%=NameInfo.ClientID").watermark('The text you want to appear');
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple alternative:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="NameInfo" CssClass="NameInfo" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Name'){this.value='';}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='Name';}" Width="300" runat="server" text="Name" />
```