# have a default text in a textbox and clear it by typing a letter on it in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css

I am developing web applications in asp.net using c#, so I placed asp:textbox in web application. When i am loading page, i want to have default text in text box and when i place cursor on it and type the first letter, the text box become clear from textbox.

Comment: That would be done with Javascript.

Comment: See my answer for a very similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762026/asp-input-field-on-click-clear-value/13762120#13762120.

Comment: Have a look at the placeholder tag for inputs.

Comment: @JonMalcolm: Dose it work for password text box?

Answer (score 1):

what you are asking is called watermarking. There are so many ways to do it

Third Party tools like :

a. Ajax ToolKit. you can see it in action [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx)

b. Telerik RadTextBox Control (by setting its *EmptyMessage* property)  .

and so many.

You can yourself build one using simple javascript like below:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 var watermark = 'textbox watermark text';
 $('#inputTextboxId').blur(function(){
  if ($(this).val().length == 0)
    $(this).val(watermark).addClass('watermark');
 }).focus(function(){
  if ($(this).val() == watermark)
    $(this).val('').removeClass('watermark');
 }).val(watermark).addClass('watermark');
});
</script>
```

and place an input control inside your container say body

```
<body>

<input id="inputTextboxId" type="text" />
</body>
```

Also, if your entire work area resides in HTML5 supported browsers,then simply do this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name...">
```

and your textbox will have watermark "Enter your name..." which would disappear on focus.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below mentioned following code it wil help to you to solve your problem

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Textbox"
             CssClass="Input" 
             onfocus="if(this.value == 'Name'){this.value='';}" 
             onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='Name';}" 
             Width="300" 
             runat="server" 
             text="Name" />
```

Comment: It works fine for my username part... but do you have any idea for password texbox. because password cant show any thing after refreshing page.

Comment: for password use another text box and use this jquery
$("#passwordText").val('Password');
$('#passwordText').show();
$('#user_password').hide();

$('#passwordText').focus(function() {
$('#passwordText').hide();
$('#user_password').show();
$('#user_password').focus();
});

$('#user_password').blur(function() {
if($('#user_password').val() == '') {
$('#passwordText').show();
$('#user_password').hide();
}
});

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is the [HTML5 Placeholder tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp), although this isn't fully supported in all browsers.

I would recommend the javascript alternative @Jon Malcolm suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [AjaxControlToolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/)'s [TextBoxWatermark extender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx). Add the AjaxControlToolkit to your project (using Nuget is the easiest way), and then in your markup you can specify the text to be displayed like this:

```
<asp:textbox runat="server" id="MyTextBox" />
<ajaxtoolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender runat="server" id="MyTextBoxExtender" TargetControlId="MyTextBox" WatermarkText="Default Text" />
```

Or you can do this with the jQuery Watermark plugin - there's details on how to implement this  in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762026/asp-input-field-on-click-clear-value/13762120#13762120).